# ¿Porque aparece '\r' al final de cada valor cuando importo mis datos? - R

Tags: r

**Buen dia.**

A continuaion les muestro como importo mis datos:

```
encig <- read_csv('conjunto_de_datos/conjunto_de_datos_encig2019_01_sec1_3_4_5_8_9_10.csv', 
              locale = locale(encoding = 'ISO-8859-1'))
print(glimpse(encig))
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tambien intente

```
encig <- read.csv('conjunto_de_datos/conjunto_de_datos_encig2019_01_sec1_3_4_5_8_9_10.csv', 
              encoding = 'latin9')
print(glimpse(encig))
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quisiera saber porque aparece "\r" o "\n" al final de cada valor y como puedo eliminarlo.

Inspeccionando el csv con el inspector de texto les puedo decir que los "\r" o "\n" no deberían aparecer.

Comment: Pues porque viene especificado en el archivo conjunto_de_datos_encig2019_01_sec1_3_4_5_8_9_10.csv, te sugerimos revisar [ask], es importante agregar más detalles tu pregunta.

Comment: No es asi, checando el csv en excel te puedo decir que los valores no tienen ese "\r".

Comment: excel es una **pésima idea** para revisar archivos CSV, pues te los va a formatear y va a presumir que es muy inteligente. Revísalos con un editor de texto (bloc de notas, notepad++,...). Es más, si guardaste o tiene autoguardado, seguro ya dañó el formato del CSV...

Comment: Ya lo inspeccione con el editor de texto y, en efecto, no deben aparecer esos caracteres.

Comment: Y si pruebas con UTF-8 en la codificación? En qué codificación viene el csv?

Comment: No estoy muy seguro pero tal vez encuentres una solucion consultando este enlace:
https://paquete-apertura-datos.readthedocs.io/es/0.1.1/guia_abiertos.html

Comment: En utf-8 aparecen las \n y caracteres especiales. No estoy seguro pero creo que el csv viene en latin9, es del INEGI

Comment: No hay forma de reproducir tu problema a menos que compartas un ejemplo del archivo CSV.

Answer (score 0):

CR LF significan Carriage Return y Line feed, es decir, en combinación significan cambie de línea. Son caracteres invisibles, pero en algunos procesadores de texto los representan con \r\n

Son los dos caracteres extraños que se presentan en tu archivo plano. Debe tener que ver con la codificación con la que fueron guardados.

Si el resto de valores son correctos, en vez de probar diversas codificaciones sin lograr resultados, lo puedes corregir mediante el comando gsub():

```
gsub(pattern = '\r', replacement = '', x = encig$ID_PER)
```

Pero como es en todas las columnas, es mejor aplicar la función apply:

```
apply(X = encig, MARGIN = 2, FUN = gsub, pattern = '\r', replacement = '')
```